# execute commands one after other in new line shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to print  commands on remote server one after other in new line

```
echo "Hostname is: `hostname`"
echo
echo "Disk Space is: `df -h /`"
echo
echo "free Space is: `free -m`
```

i get following output

```
Hostname is:   echo Disk Space is: Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  /
```

Its not printing on new line

Comment: Put your executed commands inside like `${history}` and put semicolons between `echo` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked

Answer (score 0):

Use this form instead:

```
echo "Hostname is: $(hostname)"
echo
echo "Disk Space is: $(df -h)"
echo
echo "free Space is: $(free -m)"
```